# Из-за подключаемых библиотек javascript сайт долго загружается

Tags: javascript

Подключила к сайту календарь datepicker от jquery. Теперь сайт долго загружается. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить. Нашла в интернете, что нужно поставить на внешних скриптах defer. Но не поменялось ничего.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>BANK</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker-ru.js" defer></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker-ru.js" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#minMaxExample').datepicker({
          minDate: new Date();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <table>
      <form name="calc" method="post" action="calc.php">
        <tr>
          <td>Дата оформления вклада</td>
          <td><input id="datepicker" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: а как вы замеряете скорость страницы? Почему вы загружаете не минифицированные скрипты?

Comment: код подключения скриптов на странице datepicker  взят

Comment: нужно использовать минифицированные версии скриптов, они весят в разы меньше, для начала хотя бы это попробовать

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях я просто скачиваю скрипт к себе и подключаю как локальный. Так не принято, но ведь помогает.

Comment: Были времена, когда такой подход критиковался и модно было размещать на сторонних серверах. Сейчас снова пошла мода на обратное -- всё к себе тащить и никаких сторонних скриптов не ставить.

Comment: Я подключила библиотеки mini.js. Но как выяснилось грузится долго из-за этой ссылки <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: что с этим добром сделать можно не понятно

Comment: вам уже ответили: скачайте минифицированные версии скриптов и стилей себе на сервер и подключайте оттуда. Если скриптов много, стоит объединить их в один бандл. Еще стоит убрать скрипты из секции head и поместить их перед </body>.

Comment: @Каролина Так ссылка же неправильная. Вы забыли указать `https:`

Comment: @leninel В чем смысл убирания скриптов из `<head>`?

Comment: https://stevesouders.com/hpws/move-scripts.php

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, ссылка верная. Когда не указываешь протокол, он берет тот, что на запрашиваемом сервере. Хреново это дело работает на локальной машине из-за 'file:/'

Answer (score 0):

Вот ваша проблема

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#minMaxExample').datepicker({
          minDate: new Date();
  </script>
```

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементам на странице, до того как они созданы. А в случае с `defer` еще и до того, как были загружены скрипты.

Этот код должен вызываться тогда, когда сформировано DOM дерево элементов. Т.е. из события `DOMReady`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {  // Регистрируем обработчик DOMReady
    // Теперь все элементы загружены
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    $('#minMaxExample').datepicker({
          minDate: new Date();
  });
</script>
```

Далее, если вы используете `defer`, то вы еще и получаете асинхронную загрузку скриптов. В этом случае этот код нужно выносить в отдельный JS файл и подключать его к странице через `defer` после модулей JQuery

Плюс, вместо

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
> ```

должно быть

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
                             ^^^^^^
```